# How to check via an assert that the Title Bar contains text (value of) "X" (e.g., "Error")

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a Visual Studio 2010 "CodedUITest" test and want to ensure that an error dialog appears.  The most basic option is to check (verify) the title bar contains a specific word, in my case "Error".  How would I code an assert statemnt to verify the text contains what I expect?

[Update]  "Extra points" if you can tell me how to do this for a control that has type "SunAwtDialog" (probably because this is a Java application)?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly, but I think you can use:

```
Debug.Assert(/* insert the bool condition here */);
```

So in your case, you could try:

```
Debug.Assert(myForm.Text.Contains("Error"));
```